# f-string interfering with extracting URLs

Tags: python, list, f-string

**tl;dr f-string is messing up the script below. List printed is empty despite the file containing a list of URLs. How can I fix this problem and have Python print out the URLs?**

So I have a script below. It downloads a list of URLs, converts it into a list, and then prints it out. Now, for the variable `link`, there's an f-string. If I keep just one value in the f-string (say I delete `fromdate` and `todate` and just keep `username`), it works just fine. But if I put multiple values in the f-string, the script fails.

### COMMAND

```
script.py -u mrbeast
```

### SCRIPT

```
import argparse, re, requests

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-u','--username', required=False)
parser.add_argument('-from','--fromdate', required=False)
parser.add_argument('-to','--todate', required=False)
args = vars(parser.parse_args())
username = args['username']
fromdate = args['fromdate']
todate = args['todate']

link = "https://web.archive.org/cdx/search/cdx?url=twitter.com/{}/status&matchType=prefix&from={}&to={}".format(username,fromdate,todate)
listy = []

m = requests.get(link).text
urls = re.findall(r'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', m)

for b, url in enumerate (urls):
    listy.append(f"{b}: {url}")
    
print(listy)
```

### OUTPUT

```
[]
```

Comment: if in same call you print urls what do you see?

Comment: Same output: empty list.

Comment: That just means there was no match with the regex. In order to reproduce the problem, please provide the exact value of `m`. All that happens before that assignment is irrelevant.

Comment: Also, this behaviour has nothing to do with f-strings, since your loop does not perform any iteration.

Comment: But the script works when I go down from three values to one for the f-string despite the regex being the same. Why? [Here's the URL](https://web.archive.org/cdx/search/cdx?url=twitter.com/mrbeast/status&matchType=prefix&from=&to=) that Python can't extract the URLs from. This would basically equal `m`.

Comment: [cannot reproduce the problem](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions70978854f-string-interf)

Comment: Thank you, I will continue to check and see what's exactly wrong. The script in my question just doesn't work for whatever reason, I'll see if ditching `.format()` for f-strings works better.

Comment: If you don't provide a value for, e.g., `--from`, the value of `fromdate` is `None`, not `''`, which means your URL contains `from=None`, not just `from=`. I don't think your script is using the URL you think it is.

Comment: You're right!! That's why!! Dang, is there a way to get rid of `None`, or am I out of luck? Thank you so much for your invaluable help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are experiencing this behaviour not because of f-strings, but because of  how python is formatting your link. There is no f-string being used in the variable link, just string formatting.
When passing in null values, python is feeding None into the url instead of leaving them blank like intended.
This causes the URL to look something like this

`https://web.archive.org/cdx/search/cdx?url=twitter.com/None/status&matchType=prefix&from=None&to=None`

One solution is using the or logic operator to tell python to set the variable to an empty string if the value is none. This can be done in the variable declaration.
One possible method is below

```py
username = args['username'] or '' # or logic operator converts variable to '' if None.
fromdate = args['fromdate'] or ''
todate = args['todate'] or ''
```

I hope this helped,
and welcome to stack overflow.

Comment: THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP! Using your method, I learned how to avoid None and use this from now on for my future projects. Thank you, I hope you accomplish your dreams!